# Sublime text 3: Adding a vim style :q to the command palette

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm new to sublime text 3 and I'm loving the vintage mode.  But I can't figure out how to add to the command palette.  Specifically I want to add a :q command (in my case I'd like it to close the current tab) similar to the :w command provided by vintage mode.  I've read some saying there should exist a `Default.sublime-commands` and a user version but I can't seem to find it; in fact, nothing with that extension exists on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in ST3, they hid all these files in a different place.

If you're using a mac, you need to open your application folder, find Sublime Text, right-click on it, show the content of the package, and then go to Contents > MacOS > Packages. (I don't really know about windows or Linux, but basically, you need to go where it's installed).

You'll find a lot of *.sublime-package files in there. Copy the vintage one (someplace else), rename it as a zip, unzip it, and you'll find your file.

You can then modify it, and save it. To save it, you'll need to go in Sublime, and Browse Package (this will open the folder where your own settings are saved). Create a Vintage folder in there, and put your file in it. It should work.

--Alexis

Comment: ugh.  That's rough.  I use lots of computers and I really wish this could be a line I add to my user files :(

Comment: Well actually I just explain how to retrieve the original file. But you can only create the new file in /Package/Vintage and this should work too.
You can also use something like sublimall to share your configurations between several computers.

Comment: Beautiful.  I misunderstood.  For posterity, here's the line I added to `vintage.sublime-commands`:

`{ "caption": ":q - Close", "command": "close" },`, which I then placed into `%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear the first time!
Happy it worked.